# How can I disable interpolation on a GPU canvas FMX TImage or set interpolation to "nearest neighbor"

Tags: delphi, image-processing, firemonkey

I am trying to create a pinch-to-zoom TImage function and want to disable interpolation when resizing a firemonkey TImage control (and it needs to work across multiple devices).

Setting the TImage's "DisableInterpolation" to "True" doesn't work on Windows if "GlobalUseGPUCanvas" is set to "True" or on Android (which I believe always uses a GPU canvas).

This is easily reproducible with Embarcadero's Image Zoom sample by setting "GlobalUseGPUCanvas" to "True" in the project's DPR file and checking "DisableInterpolation" on the form's TImage:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/FMX.ImageZoom_Sample

Is there a way to truly disable interpolation with a GPU canvas or somehow set the GPU resampler to use nearest neighbor instead of the default algorithm (bicubic? bilinear?)?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a TImage, you can paint directly the image on the canvas using a Texture

When you will create the texture you can assign it with GL_NEAREST instead of GL_LINEAR (IE: Texture.MagFilter)

Below the delphi function that will create the texture (for reference) :

```
class procedure TCustomContextOpenGL.DoInitializeTexture(const Texture: TTexture);
var
  Tex: GLuint;
begin
  if Valid then
  begin
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, @Tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Tex);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    case Texture.MagFilter of
      TTextureFilter.Nearest: glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
      TTextureFilter.Linear: glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    end;
    if TTextureStyle.MipMaps in Texture.Style then
    begin
      case Texture.MinFilter of
        TTextureFilter.Nearest: glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
        TTextureFilter.Linear: glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      case Texture.MinFilter of
        TTextureFilter.Nearest: glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        TTextureFilter.Linear: glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
      end;
    end;
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, Texture.Width, Texture.Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nil);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    ITextureAccess(Texture).Handle := Tex;
    if (GLHasAnyErrors()) then
      RaiseContextExceptionFmt(@SCannotCreateTexture, [ClassName]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require rewriting the entire UI in OpenGL? I am hoping for a firemonkey GPU canvas solution.

Comment: no just replacing your timage by any Tcontrol and using Ttexture to paint on it ...

Comment: I don't have previous experience using TTexture, I read about it and there are a lot of unknowns to me. Could you possibly give an example of how to replicate Embarcadero's Image Zoom sample based on a TTexture instead of the sample's TImage?

Comment: For sample you can seach for Ttexture in the code source of https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe. using texture is not different than TTbitmap, to print it you simply for exemple need to do : TCustomCanvasGpu(Canvas).DrawTexture(...);

Comment: I downloaded a zip of the repository and only found references to TTexture under "alcinoe-master\archive\source\ALFmxImgList.pas".  And it seems the TTexture code is only under Android and iOS, is there no windows support? It also seems to be using functions that are not part of the included code.  I am also generating the TImage's TBitmap about 100 times per second from other TBitmaps (basically a tile-based game), wouldn't adding another TTexture conversion step add a lot of CPU overhead?